# session handler for nodejs using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

is any session handler module available for nodejs using mysql. I already have connect-mongo for session handling using mongodb. similarly i needed for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used it, but looks like there is one here:

https://github.com/CarnegieLearning/connect-mysql-session

Comment: That module has gone unsupported for 2 years now. I created a new one (with unit and integration tests as well): https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session